# some questions about ngrx-store-freeze and [(ngModel)] in angular

Tags: angular, freeze, deep-copy, ngrx-store

I'm using `ngrx/store` and `ngrx-store-freeze` in angular. And I found something that I really don't understand.

I have a model:

```
Book {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
}
```

in my reducer, I have stored books:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Book> {
  bookId: number;
}
```

When I get `books` from store in the parent component and pass it with async to the child component, it cannot be modified undoubtedly.

But, when I deep clone `books`, it still cannot be modified. I tried `lodash.cloneDeep()`,`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`, cannot be modified.

The interesting thing is when I use `Object.isFrozen()` to test every variable whether it is from ngrx/store or not, the result is always true.

Is there anyone knowing something about this?

Comment: This cannot be true. It does not matter if you pass the object down the chain or not if you do "const newBooks  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(books))" you will be able to modify the newBooks object without freez getting in the way since you are creating a new object with a new reference that does not affect the store.

Comment: @IvanMihaylov yes, I understan that. But I did try every way to clone the value from store, it just cannot be modified. I really don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

solved, There are some bugs between the component I used and ngrx-store-freeze